# Error using mex Unknown file extension ' '. Matlab Ubuntu

Tags: matlab, compiler-errors, g++, mex

Please help me compiling mex file in Matlab 2018b Ubuntu20. I get
*Error using mex

Unknown file extension ' '.*
The compiler setup compiler is g++, as can be seen in the command window. The header files and libs are located in the two folders defined as path1 and path2.
The code for mex commpilations is

```
path1 = '/usr/local/include/OpenEXR/';
path2 = '/usr/local/lib/';
mex ('/mnt/D/D/ZJU Data/HDR/softwre/MatlabEXR/exrinfo.cpp',  path1,path2)
```

I have also tried as
mex exrinfo.cpp  /usr/local/lib/ /usr/local/include/OpenEXR/
Why do I get the unknown file extension error?

[image]

Comment: Its strange that you have a space between `mex` and `(` but I don't think that it. Maybe there is some hidden unicode characters in those variables, and it gets confused?

Comment: @AnderBiguri it does not make any effect in Matlab. I even tried without space and without parenthesis and commas e.g. 'mex '/mnt/D/D/ZJU Data/HDR/softwre/MatlabEXR/exrinfo.cpp'  path1 path2'

Comment: try to type the filepath by hand yourself. There are zero-width characters that you can not see and may be in that text.

Comment: @AnderBiguri This is a tangent but it's actually in the Octave style guide to *always* use a space before function parenthesis ([wiki](https://wiki.octave.org/Octave_style_guide)), and it's perfectly valid MATLAB syntax

Comment: @AnderBiguri I tried putting manually like this 'mex exrinfo.cpp /usr/local/lib/ /usr/local/include/OpenEXR/' but its not making any change. It should not actually change because the syntax is different but actually its the same.

Comment: @Wolfie WOW I hate that! :D But indeed its valid. Kanjoo, what do you mean its not making any difference? you still get that error of the file extension?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes, still same error.

Comment: No idea, you will need to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please review the syntax for the `mex` command [in the online documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html).

Arguments passed into it are interpreted either as source files, or as flags. Flags always start with “`-`“. Since `path1` and `path2` don’t start with “`-`“, they are interpreted as source files. But they have no extension, which `mex` tries to use to guess what language they’re written in, hence the error.

You probably meant to do:

```
path1 = '-I/usr/local/include/OpenEXR/';
path2 = '-L/usr/local/lib/';
```

(“`-I`” for include path, and “`-L`” for library path.)

Comment: You are right. To compile full library, I need to put some other folders as well. Thank you.